# aws cli put-bucket-encryption command fails with validation error for BucketKeyEnabled param

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, aws-cli, amazon-kms

I want to enable SSE-KMS encryption on AWS S3 bucket and apply an existing KMS key to the bucket and also want to set the `Bucket Key` to *true*.

**AWS CLI put-bucket-encryption v2 doc:** https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-encryption.html

I followed the above mentioned aws cli documentation for `put-bucket-encryption` and ran following command but got the validation error for `BucketKeyEnabled` param.
If I remove that param then the command runs fine and sets the KMS key correctly.
However, I also want to set the `Bucket Key` to *true*.

What's wrong with my command? I did compare the AWS CLI version v1 and v2 documentation and both looks same for `put-bucket-encryption`.
Is this an aws cli version

**Command:**

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption \
    --bucket my-bucket \
    --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules":[{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault":{"SSEAlgorithm":"aws:kms","KMSMasterKeyID":"AWS_KMS_key_ARN"},"BucketKeyEnabled":true}]}'
```

**Error:**

> Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in
> ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration.Rules[0]: "BucketKeyEnabled", must
> be one of: ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault

Following is my aws cli version info:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.306 Python/2.7.16 Darwin/20.5.0 botocore/1.13.42
```

As per documentation it should, but does this version not support `BucketKeyEnabled` param? would updating to the latest aws cli version help?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the command. What is your CLI version?

Comment: @Marcin it is `aws-cli/1.16.306`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version `aws-cli/1.16.306` is **very old**, and `BucketKeyEnabled` is not supported in the old version. If you want to keep using v1 of CLI, use the latest version which is `1.24.7`. Otherwise change to the current version `2.7.11`.

Comment: Upgraded to `aws-cli/2.7.11` and the command worked. Thanks Marcin